# Facebook Graph API call not working from outside

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a web page to login to Facebook and then once logged in, create a session which stores the access token and also the user id. And then I redirect the user to a profile page where it pulls the information from user's facebook posts via a Graph API call and then presents the information. I'm using PHP to get the Graph API.

It's working fine on my local machine and I can see the data just as I want. But when I access the same link from outside my home network, It displays a blank page. I can still login from outside the home network so that piece of code works fine, but it is unable to pull the user_posts. There's nothing wrong with the code as far as I understand otherwise I won't be able to access the link even from my local network.

I tried many different solutions, added a whitelist of IPaddresses (but it may be that I'm not adding them in the correct place). I'm at a total loss. Has someone experienced a similar situation? If adding the specific ip addresses would help, where do I add them exactly. There are so many confusing fields in the Facebook developers settings.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: _“It displays a blank page”_ – what language are you using for your app, PHP? If so, make sure you have proper error reporting enabled (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death), and also make sure that your script handles all exceptions the PHP SDK (if you’re using that) might throw properly.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, it was a settings issue.